# Abort a Datastage job at a specified time

Tags: datastage

I have a scheduled parallel Datastage (11.7) job.
This job has a **Hive Connector** with a Before and After Statement.

The before statement run ok but After statement remains in running state for several hours (on Hue Log i see this job finished in 1hour) and i have to manually abort it on Datastage Director.

Is there the way to **"program an abort"**?
For example i want schedule the interruption of the running job every morning at 6.

I hope I was clear :)

Comment: can you setup some cronjob/scheduled task to abort/kill Datastage job at 6 ?

Comment: do i need admin rights? where can i setup it?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you can kill the job - as per other responses - using dsjob to stop the job, this may have no effect because the After statement has been issued synchronously; the job is waiting for it to finish, and (probably) not processing kill signals and the like in the meantime.  You would be better advised to work out why the After command is taking too long, and addressing that.